# Persist loop with key duplication in symfony 5.3

Tags: loops, symfony, duplicates, key, persist

I have a loop with a persistence object in a controller:

```
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $courserepository = $em->getRepository(Course::class);
            $courseByRepository = $courserepository->findCourseByFiveParameters($timestamp, $grille, $reunion, $courseNumber, $emailstring);
            
            //persist all cheval
            $num = (int)($request->request->get('loop'));
            $chevalArray = array();
           
            for($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++){
                $cheval = new Cheval;
                $cheval->setTimestamp($timestamp);
                $cheval->setEmail($email);
                $cheval->setGrille($grille);
                $cheval->setReunion($reunion);
                $cheval->setCourseNumber($courseNumber);
                $cheval->setNumero(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('numero'.$i)));
                $cheval->setNom(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('nom'.$i)));
                $cheval->setAge(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('age'.$i)));
                $cheval->setSexe(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('sexe'.$i)));
                $cheval->setCorde(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('corde'.$i)));
                $cheval->setOeilleres(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('oeilleres'.$i)));
                $cheval->setFerrage(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('ferrage'.$i)));
                $cheval->setNbreCourses(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('nbreCourses'.$i)));
                $cheval->setVictoires(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('victoires'.$i)));
                $cheval->setPlaces(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('places'.$i)));
                $cheval->setGains(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('gains'.$i)));
                $cheval->setHandPoids(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('handPoids'.$i)));
                $cheval->setEntraineur(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('entraineur'.$i)));
                $cheval->setJockey(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('jockey'.$i)));
                $cheval->setDistance(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('distance'.$i)));
                $cheval->setMusique(htmlspecialchars($request->request->get('musique'.$i)));
                //ManyToOne
                $course->getId($courseByRepository->getId());
                $cheval->setCourse($course);
                //add to array
                $chevalArray[] = $cheval;
                //persist array[key]
                $manager->persist($chevalArray[$i-1]);
            }
            $manager->flush();
```

but the primary key is duplicate:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '42' for key 'cheval.PRIMARY'
```

I'd tried to persist just with:

```
                $cheval = new Cheval;
                $cheval->setTimestamp($timestamp);
                $cheval->setEmail($email);
...
                $manager->persist($cheval);
                $manager->flush;
```

AND flush outside the loop:

```
                }
                $manager->flush;
```

Why the key is keep in memory while I reinstance the object for each turn of the loop ?!

Comment: Is the EntityManagerInteface needs 2 instances for 2 persistences, I have more than one in this controller method...

Comment: `$manager->persist($cheval);` will work just fine.  The fact that your duplicate id is '42' (the answer to life, universe and everything) strongly implies that your code somewhere that is setting the id.  Your $course code is also a bit suspicious though probably unrelated.

Comment: Yes, in fact I persist in a loop, and the id 42 which is duplicated is the first id of the loop, from the 2nd persistence, the profiler launches the error mentioned above, I do not set the id, c It's the object manager who must take care of it, I'm going to try to make a 2nd instance of the EntityManagerInterface, otherwise I don't understand where the error is...

Comment: I had a missing course_id field, I forgot to do a "php bin/console make:entity" in a migration, but now I can't generate the courseId field in the database, I did make:migration and doctrine:migrations:migrate and nothing to do the field is non-existent...
Now I erased and remade my entity with make:entity and chose ManyToOne in the type choice with nullable to false and the entities: User for email and Course for courseId,
it works...

Comment: Never cared for the whole migration nonsense myself.  At least for development.  Next time you need to make changes, take a look at the doctrine:schema:update,create,drop commands.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the response I had a OneToMany taf for my entity, Nox I just switched to ManyToOne & it fine works, Thank you for All...